# VBA Newbie, Trying to correct date outputs

Tags: vba, excel

The program simply outputs a list of the sheets that qualified as a "plus" status along with the date that they qualified on.

[image]

I am currently attempting to insure that the dates that nothing qualified on are outputted with a "0" in the adjacent field instead of the name of the sheet. The current program does not do this and want to know what commands i need to add.

[image]

```
Sub FilterPlusData()

Dim oWbk As Workbook
Dim oSht As Worksheet
Dim oShtDestiny As Worksheet
Dim iLoop As Integer
Dim iFirstRow As Integer
Dim iRows As Integer
Dim iRowDestiny As Integer

Set oWbk = ThisWorkbook
Set oShtDestiny = oWbk.Worksheets("OUTPUT")
iFirstRow = 4

For Each oSht In oWbk.Worksheets
    If oSht.Name <> "OUTPUT" Then
        If oSht.Range("$A$2").Value = "Date" Then
            iRows = oSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For iLoop = iFirstRow To iRows
                If oSht.Cells(iLoop, 19).Value = "PLUS" Then
                    With oShtDestiny
                    iRowDestiny = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                  .Cells(iRowDestiny, 1).Value = oSht.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value
                  .Cells(iRowDestiny, 2).Value = oSht.Name

                    End With
                End If
            Next iLoop
        End If
    End If
Next oSht

'Order Ascendent
iRowDestiny = oShtDestiny.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
With oShtDestiny.Sort
    .SetRange Range("$A$3:C" & iRowDestiny)
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you have code that can output sheet name for one condition but not know how to output `0` for the opposite???

Comment: Because I suck at VBA and this was all I could figure out. :'(
-jon

Comment: Uh I don't think you figured out anything. If you did, you'd know exactly what to do XD

Comment: The term you are looking for is `Else` it is part of the `If` function.  It allows you to do something when the `If` returns a false.

Comment: Haha Thank you @Scott for the "else" definition, but unfortunately I do already understand that. The "Else" Statement I need is beyond what i have ACTUALLY learned and done (it may have taken me days).
The output currently is obviously calling the dates that are associated with the sheets name, but I can not simply tell it to enter in the next available date as "0". I need to write the else statement to check the dates against a very specific range and not have it output zero for every sheet.

Comment: Not looking for someone to write it for me, just looking for someone who has more know how to give some advice.

Comment: `check the dates against a very specific range` What Range?  You might want to edit your original post with more information.  maybe a picture of the data and what you are trying to output.  It has been a long day and my brain is not firing on all cylinders.

Comment: Thanks Scott, This is my first post on here so thank you for the help. The Dates in that picture although not random are indeed missing dates. So hopefully you can see my where my lack of knowledge makes searching a range to make changes to my previous output is confusing for me.

Comment: Reading at your code, you are basically looping through all your sheets (except for OUTPUTS) and each time that you find a date which is qualified as PLUS, you're copying it (along with the name of the sheet) into the spreadsheet OUTPUT. So in the end you find yourself with a list of dates + source sheet name which are qualified as PLUS. How exactly do you expect to have dates that are not qualified as PLUS somewhere into the sheet OUTPUT, if the only dates you're adding to this are the ones qualified as PLUS?

Comment: As a quick-and-dirty, why not just add an Else to your If statement that does the exact same thing as you have, but change the line '.Cells(iRowDestiny, 2).Value = oSht.Name' to '.Cells(iRowDestiny, 2).Value = 0'?  Wouldn't that do what you want?

Comment: Exactly, if you really want to see the dates that are not qualified as PLUS with a "0" close to it in the OUTPUTS sheet, then @Brad just gave you the exact solution.

Comment: @Matteo you are very correct, I taught myself enough VBA to do just the simple code above. This was a last minute change that I now have to do for reasons beyond me. Am I going To have to write a section to insert the  needed dates with the "0" after the output?

Comment: Sorry just saw your post update @Brad

Comment: @Jonathan Alling, if that is what will work for your issue, I'll put it below as an answer that can be accepted.

Comment: I think it should ! let me tinker with it @Brad. You guys are awesome, thanks for being patient with me. I am VERY new here, How do i give you guys good reputation?

Comment: @JonathanAlling if Brad's solution will work, he'll write it as an answer to the post. Then you'll just accept it (and upvote it, if useful ;) ) to give him the deserved credit / to communicate other users with your same issue that this is the correct solution.

Comment: my rep is not high enough to upvote -_- sorry Brad

Comment: No worries.  Just glad I could help.

Comment: No worries, @Brad will have it from me for having been the only one really understanding your request ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick-and-dirty, why not just add an `Else` to your `If` statement that does the exact same thing as you have, but change the line `.Cells(iRowDestiny, 2).Value = oSht.Name` to `.Cells(iRowDestiny, 2).Value = 0`? Wouldn't that do what you want?

```
If oSht.Cells(iLoop, 19).Value = "PLUS" Then
    With oShtDestiny
        iRowDestiny = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(iRowDestiny, 1).Value = oSht.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value
        .Cells(iRowDestiny, 2).Value = oSht.Name
    End With
Else
    With oShtDestiny
        iRowDestiny = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(iRowDestiny, 1).Value = oSht.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value
        .Cells(iRowDestiny, 2).Value = "0"
    End With
End If
```